# Can I install ruby gems for a specific ruby version?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install rubygem - mongo_mapper, but it fails because activesupport gem requires ruby version higher/equal to 1.9.3.

My question is - Is there a way to install mongo_mapper gem that knows what ruby version i'm running therefore installing all the compatible gems required in the mongo_mapper installation?

The error I'm getting is :

```
gem install mongo_mapper

ERROR:  Error installing mongo_mapper:
        activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
```

I've tried installing different versions of activesupport, and other gems mongo_mapper needs but I don't think that's the right (and easy) way to go.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not ActiveSupport, it's the Ruby version. What version of Ruby are you running? You should probably be using 2.0 or later.

Comment: i'm using ruby 1.8.7, is there anyway around upgrading ruby?

Comment: No, I don't think so. 1.8.7 is very old. Is there any special reason to not upgrade?